How to resolve dependency conflict between next-auth and @next-auth/prisma-adapter
I am encountering a dependency conflict while trying to use next-auth with the @next-auth/prisma-adapter. Here's the error I get:
PS C:\Users\adeep\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\next\donotbuy> npm install next-auth@latest
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: donotbuy@0.1.0
npm error Found: next@15.0.4-canary.13
npm error node_modules/next
npm error   next@"^15.0.4-canary.13" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer next@"^12.2.5 || ^13 || ^14 || ^15" from next-auth@4.24.10
npm error node_modules/next-auth
npm error   next-auth@"4.24.10" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\adeep\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-16T16_34_53_050Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\adeep\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-16T16_34_53_050Z-debug-0.log

What I Tried:
Upgrading next-auth:
Uninstalled next-auth (npm uninstall next-auth) and reinstalled the latest version using npm install next-auth@latest.
Still facing issues.
Using --legacy-peer-deps and --force:
Tried installing with npm install @next-auth/prisma-adapter --legacy-peer-deps and npm install @next-auth/prisma-adapter --force. This bypassed the error but caused runtime issues because of incompatibility.
Downgrading @next-auth/prisma-adapter:
Experimented with earlier versions of @next-auth/prisma-adapter to match next-auth@3.x.x. Still couldn’t find a compatible setup.
Environment:
Node.js version: v16.20.0
npm version: 8.19.2
next-auth version: 3.24.0-canary.0
@next-auth/prisma-adapter version: 1.0.7
Question:
How can I resolve this dependency conflict and set up next-auth with the @next-auth/prisma-adapter? Is there a specific version combination that works? Or do I need to configure something differently?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Found the answer Downgrade Next 15.3.3 to 15.0.0
